# How to use the AVCaptureStillImageOutput to capture the screen in Mac

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I want to capture the screen of Mac and I know AVCaptureStillImageOutput is worked.But I don't know how to use it in Mac.

I hope someone can give me some sample code about using the class to capture the screen.Or some advice is OK.

The following code is using AVCaptureStillImageOutput to capture the picture in the IOS devices.Maybe it can be modified and use in the Mac?

Any help is appreciated,thanks in advance.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////
//// Utility to find front camera
////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////
    -(AVCaptureDevice *) frontFacingCameraIfAvailable{
    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice
    devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){

      if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront){

        captureDevice = device;
        break;
    }
}

//  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
if (!captureDevice){

    captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
}

return captureDevice;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////
//// Setup Session, attach Video Preview Layer
//// and Capture Device, start running session
////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void) setupCaptureSession {
AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer    alloc] initWithSession:session];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

NSError *error = nil;
AVCaptureDevice *device = [self frontFacingCameraIfAvailable];
AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
if (!input) {
    // Handle the error appropriately.
    NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
}
[session addInput:input];

self.stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
[self.stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

[session addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];

[session startRunning];
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////
////
//// Method to capture Still Image from 
//// Video Preview Layer
////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void) captureNow {
AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections) {
    for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
        if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] ) {
            videoConnection = connection;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (videoConnection) { break; }
}

NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", self.stillImageOutput);
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
[self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {

     NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
     UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

     [weakSelf displayImage:image];
 }];
    }
```

Comment: Capturing the screen meaning you are talking about making a movie of desktop activity?

Comment: Capturing a still image of screen. Actually I want to send the recording video of desktop activity to a multicast group while the video is being recorded. I don't know how to send the stream media to the Network, so continuously sending images instead of sending stream media is the only solution I can think of.

Comment: You confirm for one and want to do another.  I don't know what you want.

Comment: Just want to capture a still image of the screen.

Comment: See Apple's sample project called AVScreenShack.

Comment: I did see that project,but it just has the code about recording screen activity as a movie.Np code about capture a image of screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to take a screen capture.

Here is what I use in iOS to take a picture of entire view (screenCapture),

```
UIView *wholeScreen = self.view;

// define the size and grab a UIImage from it
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(wholeScreen.bounds.size, wholeScreen.opaque, 0.0);
[wholeScreen.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *screengrab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

I do not know if this will work on OSX.

Edit - Ok, the above doesn't work, maybe you can see if this can help you, [ScreenShot Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/ScreenSnapshot/Introduction/Intro.html)

Here is a description about what this does - Uses Quartz Display Services to obtain an image containing the contents of any of the connected displays. Also allows the user to save the image to a file on disk.

Comment: I did not even find the “UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()”.It‘s just use in the iOS.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer with a link to an Apple Doc with code on how to capture the screen and save to a file.

Comment: bro. I get it. Just modify the code I posted.Anyway thanks my friend.

Comment: So, you know how to do it but you want me to write it out for you?? If you want to screen capture you wouldn't use the method you posted. That is why I am giving you new code.

Comment: Sorry bro.I spent much time to modify the code.when I worked it,I came here to tell you.Then  I saw your updated answer....